# SSRS - How to fit the content of a table into a single page for each table and not have part of the table spread between 2 pages

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-tablix

I have the following table (see the table below). It is querying into a table in my database, which has around 10 000 lines.

[image]

It starts well as you can (also below)

[image]

Issue is when going to the second page and after, the table is spreading around.

**updated version after my wrong description**: What I want actually is to have several tables in one page , with the last table complete with the 8 rows at the end of the page and have the next table start on another page.

I tried to set the tablix and the **rectangle** ,with the following properties:

```
 General
     KeepTogether = True
 PageBreak
     BreakLocation = End
     Disabled = False
     ResetPageNumber = False
```

However, it is still not giving me the desired results.

Any tips are more than welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your table inside a List Item, and deactivate the `Add a page break after`  in the List.

Or if you want to fit as many tables as possible on a page, but keep the page break from splitting them, here is how I have done this in the past:

1. Create a sub-report that contains a single tablix for a single data entry.
2. Put a single-celled tablix on your main report that gets the list of data entries for the full report.
3. Put a rectangle inside the single cell.
4. Put the sub-report inside the rectangle, and pass it the ID of the data entry.

Comment: Look at the bold part

Comment: Right, I see the word rectangle, but I don't see where it is in your report layout.   Is it just around the table?    If so, then you don't need it.

Comment: Indeed. I'm saying below the table but you understood it correctly when you are saying it is around the table

Comment: Ok then I don't think you need the rectangle, but it doesn't hurt to keep it either, so up to you.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong description of my problem. What you gave me , almost solve my problem. What I want actually is to have several tables in one page , with the last table complete with the 8 rows at the end of the page and have the next table start on another page.

Comment: Many thanks for your precious insight. After some tweaking, I've deactivated the `add a page break after` and things are fine! Thanks again and happy holidays!